# What' the difference between /var/log and -/var/log in rsyslog.conf on RPi B?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, rsyslog

I've noticed in my `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file that some destination got that symbol "-" in front of it. For example:

```
mail.info        -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn        -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err         /var/log/mail.err
```

or

```
news.crit        -/var/log/news/news.crit
news.err         /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice      /var/log/news/news.notice
```

I couldn't find answer for that or maybe wasn't looking deep enough. I've started my journey with RPi 3 days ago. I've got no experience at all. Well I do have some now :) Managed to set up working iptables properly and log them to different file excluding from `/etc/log/kern.log` which isn't probably a big deal at all I suppose...

However, what's the difference between `-/var/` and just `/var/`?

My Rpi is using Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy).

Radek

Answer (score 0):

From the manpage `RSYSLOG.CONF(5)`:

```
By default, files are not synced after earch write. To  enable  syncing
of log files globally, use either the "$ActionFileEnableSync" directive
or the "sync" parameter to omfile. Enabling this option  degrades  per‐
formance  and  it is advised not to enable syncing unless you know what
you are doing.  To selectively disable syncing for certain  files,  you
may prefix the file path with a minus sign ("-").
```

So if syncing is enabled, it seems to be advisable to exclude those files that are expected to be written to a lot. If syncing is diabled (default) the minus sign should not make any difference.

Comment: Ok, So I feel stupid now that I didn't read the whole manpage... Cheers for that.
 
How to check the status of file syncing on my RPi? 

I will have to read more about syncing itself. Im wondering why would I need syncing and what it is actually :)

Comment: Well, I really don't know a lot about rsyslog and only solved your initial question by means of the manpage. I think it will have something to do with syncing between the local and a remote system, so it might not even apply to your particular case. Probably, a closer look at the manpage of the acual deamon, `RSYSLOGD(8)` could provide some useful informtion on the topic. Maybe also consult http://www.rsyslog.com/guides-for-rsyslog/.

Comment: So I found that -- to me -- it is not quite clear from the documentation what "syncing" means however, it can most likely be interpreted as this: "files are not synced after each write" -- A "write" doesn't actually seems to be a wirte to the file but rather "the writing of a message to rsyslog", which is then processed. From what I understand from the officiall documentation and other sources, I assume that rsyslog tries to collect more messages before eventually writing them to disc (after a certain waiting time or number of messages received).

Comment: While definitely increasing performance under heavy logging load with huge logfiles, it obviously increases the chance of data loss in case of a crash, as all messages that have not been synced to disk cannot be recoverd. So you will have to chose what is more important in your case or find the right trade-off.